# How to keep value constant in recursive function?

Tags: python, function, recursion, constants

Example:

```
def func(n):
    if n > 10:
        return
    CONSTANT = n
    print(n + CONSTANT)
    func(n + 1)

>>> func(1)
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11

>>> func(7)
14
15
16
17
```

Obviously this specific task can be achieved via different routes, but I'm wondering if this is possible to do: have a constant value in a recursive function that's expressed in terms of a changing variable.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What value should be constant?

Comment: @Barmar The one named CONSTANT. My goal is to have it be defined on the very first call of the function (defined as CONSTANT = n) and stay that value for all the coming iterations, as the output suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it an optional parameter that you only pass in the recursive calls.

```
def func(n, CONSTANT = None):
    if n > 10:
        return
    if CONSTANT is None:
        CONSTANT = n
    print(n + CONSTANT)
    func(n + 1, CONSTANT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just make the value you passed as argument a global variable and access it from your function?

Comment: Wouldn't I then have to create a global variable for all different values that I want to call the function with? I don't think that's what I'm looking for.